# audiowaveform error (No such file or directory #include "gmock/gmock.h") while installing on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, audiowaveform

I have been installing and using audiowaveform on AWS Elastic Beanstalk via an ebextensions but for some reason I now get an error during the build process:

```
...
[ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/audiowaveform_tests.dir/src/WavFileWriter.cpp.o 
[ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/audiowaveform_tests.dir/src/madlld-1.1p1/bstdfile.c.o 
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/audiowaveform_tests.dir/test/FileFormatTest.cpp.o 
/opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/test/FileFormatTest.cpp:26:25: 
fatal error: gmock/gmock.h: No such file or directory #include "gmock/gmock.h" ^ compilation terminated. 
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/audiowaveform_tests.dir/test/FileFormatTest.cpp.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/audiowaveform_tests.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2.
```

Below is the ebextension that I have been using:

```
    packages:
    yum:
        make: []
        cmake: []
        gcc-c++: []
        gd-devel: []
        boost-devel: []

sources:
    /opt/src/audiowaveform: https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform/archive/master.zip
    /opt/src/googletest: https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.tar.gz
    /opt/src/libmad: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mad/files/libmad/0.15.1b/libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz/download
    /opt/src/libsndfile: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.28.tar.gz
    /opt/src/libid3tag: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mad/files/libid3tag/0.15.1b/libid3tag-0.15.1b.tar.gz/download

files:
    /usr/lib/pkgconfig/mad.pc:
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            prefix=/usr
            exec_prefix=${prefix}
            libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
            includedir=${prefix}/include

            Name: mad
            Description: MPEG audio decoder
            Requires:
            Version: 0.15.1b
            Libs: -L${libdir} -lmad
            Cflags: -I${includedir}

    /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libsndfile:
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            /usr/lib/

commands:
    00-install-libmad-make:
        command: "sed -i '/-fforce-mem/d' configure"
        cwd: /opt/src/libmad/libmad-0.15.1b/

    01-install-libmad-make:
        command: "./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install"
        cwd: /opt/src/libmad/libmad-0.15.1b
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    02-install-libsndfile-make:
        command: "./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --docdir=/usr/share/doc/libsndfile-1.0.28 && make && make install"
        cwd: /opt/src/libsndfile/libsndfile-1.0.28
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    03-install-libid3tag-make:
        command: "./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install"
        cwd: /opt/src/libid3tag/libid3tag-0.15.1b
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    04-change-mod-audiowaveform:
        command: "chmod -R 755 audiowaveform-master"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform

    05-audiowaveform-ln-test:
        command: "ln -s ../../googletest/googletest-release-1.10.0/googletest ./googletest"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/
        test: "[ ! -L ./googletest ]"

    06-audiowaveform-ln-mock:
        command: "ln -s ../../googletest/googletest-release-1.10.0/googlemock ./googlemock"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/
        test: "[ ! -L ./googlemock ]"

    07-audiowaveform-mkdir-build:
        command: "sudo mkdir build"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/
        test: "[ ! -d ./build ]"

    08-audiowaveform-cmake:
        command: "cmake .."
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/build/
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    09-audiowaveform-make:
        command: "make"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/build/
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    10-audiowaveform-make-install:
        command: "make install"
        cwd: /opt/src/audiowaveform/audiowaveform-master/build/
        test: "[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/audiowaveform ]"

    11-ldconfig:
        command: "ldconfig"
```

Anyone know of something that has changed?  So far I haven't found anything.

Do I need to use a different process?  I am really not sure what to do next.  I have created an new application and environment and tried deploying to it to make sure I haven't messed up the current one but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like it is a version issue.  This was on our dev environment and found out it was trying to install version 1.5.1 and our production version is on 1.4.2.  So I changed the

/opt/src/audiowaveform: https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform/archive/master.zip

to

/opt/src/audiowaveform: https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform/archive/refs/tags/1.4.2.zip

and changed all the references to audiowaveform-master to audiowaveform-1.4.2 in the commands below and it seems to work.

Currently we are on a deprecated platform so am transitioning to a supported platform at the same time so I haven't made sure that it works completely but at least it builds it.